# How does Ehrman support his assertion that the "we" passages in Acts represent a false claim to eyewitness status for those particular events?

Tags: acts, authorship, bart-ehrman

A Wikipedia article on the [Authorship of Luke–Acts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorship_of_Luke%E2%80%93Acts) has a quote from Bart E. Ehrman commenting on the stylistic insertions of the "we" passage as indicating a forgery:

> According to Bart D. Ehrman, the "we" passages are written by someone
> falsely claiming to have been a travelling companion of Paul, in order
> to present the untrue idea that the author had firsthand knowledge of
> Paul's views and activities. Ehrman holds that The Acts of the
> Apostles is thereby shown to be a forgery.

The traditional view is that Luke wrote Acts and Luke traveled with Paul on some of his journeys, so the "we" passages are the parts of the journey where Luke was present. On what grounds does Ehrman push back against this view, so as to make the case that these stylistic changes prove the book is a forgery?

Comment: The *we* of Acts seems similar to that of John.

Comment: What is a 'traditional' Christian ?

Comment: The traditional view is that Luke wrote Acts and Luke traveled with Paul on some of his journeys, so the "we" passages are exactly the parts of the journey where Luke was present.

Comment: Thanks. I took most of the above comments and made some changes to my original question.

Comment: IMO, the body of the question now represents a well-formed question. I've updated the title to match it in order for the question to receive more appropriate attention than that which the previous title would more likely attract. @jess if you don't approve, it is quite easy to revert to your previous edit [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/86766/revisions).